# Odoo v11.0 testing

Tags: testng, odoo-11

I am new to odoo. I am using odoo v11.00 I am trying to test a model of my custom module.

Here is the file structure

```
course_management
|-- ...
`-- tests
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- test_course_management_course.py
```

Here is the the content of test_course_management_course.py file

```
from odoo.tests import common


class TestCourseManagement(common.TransactionCase):

    def test_creation_end_date(self):
        test_course = self.env['course.management.course'].create({
            'name': 'TestProjectfromtestcase'
        })
        self.assertEqual(test_course.name, 'TestProject')
```

And the commands I have tried are as follows

```
./odoo-bin -c /home/bs632/odoo.conf -u course_management --test-enable -d testDB


./odoo-bin -c /home/bs632/odoo.conf --log-level=test -u course_management --test-enable -d testDB --test-report-directory=./testlog.


./odoo-bin -c /home/bs632/odoo.conf --log-level=test -u course_management --test-enable -d testDB


./odoo-bin -c /home/bs632/odoo.conf --log-level=test -i course_management --test-enable -d testDB
```

But the test doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with odoo for 9 years and I can say, that odoo testing sucks. In vanilla installation 11.0 you are not able to run single test unit, case or test single module. You can run "all or nothing", but when you write a single test unit, running "everything" has totally no sense. It was changed in odoo 12.0 with test tags, where you can run command like that:

```
python odoo-bin --test-tags nice,standard
```

But it still doesn't support running single test units, cases or modules. I don't know why odoo didn't fix it even in version 15.0. Unfortunately it doesn't support controllers testing (HttpCase).

Odoo tests are written in unittest module, but command like

```
python -m unittest discover course_management
```

won't work with odoo, because it won't be wrapped in odoo server. Basically you will get info that odoo couldn't be imported.

I find odoo to be one of the best python frameworks, but without "normal" tests most of custom created code by third party developers has usually poor quality. During my 9 years of experience, none of the companies I worked for wrote tests. You can find some module for that in odoo apps.